# Select group of items based on metadata

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have several sets of items, sets partially intersect. All sets contain source files. Every such set must be compiled separately. The way I was hoping to achieve this was by means of using metadata, but I just cannot figure out the way. Below is my setup:

```
<Content Include="src\Source.ts">
  <Integration>integration</Integration>
  <Development>development</Development>
</Content>
... <!-- more sources -->
<DeployLabel Include="deploy\integration\foo.js">
  <Dir>integration\</Dir>
</DeployLabel>
... <!-- more targets --->
<DeployLabel Include="deploy\integration\bar.js">
  <Dir>development\</Dir>
</DeployLabel>
<Target Inputs="@(DeployLabel)" Name="GenericDeploy" Outputs="%(Identity).Dummy">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Deployroot>deploy\%(DeployLabel.Dir)</Deployroot>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="Deploying: $$(Deploydir)"/>
    <!-- how to select here only the TypeScriptCompile files
         such that have metadata matching DeployLabel.Dir -->
    <Exec Command="tsc --target ES3 -c -d --out $$(Deployroot) @(TypeScriptCompile -&gt;'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')"/>
  </Target>
```

I'm generating the project file, so if it can be done differently, but in automatic way - that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter items by using condition and batching.
I’m using two approaches depending on situation if I need metadata of item or not.

1. Target Filter1 copies items by Identity but does not retain original metadata.
2. Target Filter2 copies items including metadata's and then removes item I don’t want. Advantage of the Filter2 is that you have all original metadata.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <DeployLabel Include="deploy\integration\foo.js">
            <Dir>integration\</Dir>
            <T>1</T>
        </DeployLabel>
        <DeployLabel Include="deploy\integration\foo2.js">
            <Dir>integration\</Dir>
            <T>2</T>
        </DeployLabel>
        <DeployLabel Include="deploy\integration\foo3.js">
            <Dir>integration\</Dir>
            <T>3</T>
        </DeployLabel>
        <DeployLabel Include="deploy\integration\bar.js">
            <Dir>development\</Dir>
            <T>0</T>
        </DeployLabel>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Filter1">
        <ItemGroup>
            <_DeployLabelHelper Include="%(DeployLabel.Identity)" Condition=" 'integration\' == '%(DeployLabel.Dir)' " />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Message Text="@(_DeployLabelHelper->'%(Identity):%(T)')"/>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Filter2">
        <ItemGroup>
            <_RemovalHelper Include="%(DeployLabel.Identity)" Condition=" 'integration\' != '%(DeployLabel.Dir)' " />
            <_DeployLabelHelper Include="@(DeployLabel)" />
            <_DeployLabelHelper Remove="@(_RemovalHelper)" />
        </ItemGroup>

        <Message Text="@(_DeployLabelHelper->'%(Identity):%(T)')"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```